# htm how to use hover tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

if i have index.html file with code as:

```
        <li><a href="#">QA</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="1.html">current-status</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="2.html">update status</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">WESKO</a>
         <ul>
                <li><a href="1.html">current-status</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="2.html">update status</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">PUBLIC</a>

           <ul>
                <li><a href="1.html">current-status</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="2.html">update status</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">DEV</a>

             <ul>
                <li><a href="1.html">current-status</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="2.html">update status</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

1.html it has some text boxes and details are being fetched in textboxes which I'am reading from some file ,I want something, if I
hover a mouse on QA (current-status,i.e 1.html) It should dispaly or pop-up that 1.html page with all the information loaded

Comment: Use a tooltip or at least a title attribute

Comment: You can put a bootstrap script of tooltip, and then add ad title attr. to your a href.

Answer (score 1):

Add a title attribute to the tag to show the text on hover

```html
<a href="#" title="Public links">PUBLIC</a>
```

Comment: i want to show the data there which is linked to 1.html and 2.html

Comment: Add title for the 1.html and 2.html just like the above example.